# Swift: switching on enums without a switch statement

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

With Optionals you can easily check a result and either use a non-nil or pass on a nil, with one line:

```
guard x = couldReturnNil() else { return nil }
// After here, x can be used safely. Calling function
// can do the same, so nil gets passed back down the calling stack.
```

This makes return-type error handling easy. What I'd like is a similar one-liner for other enums. Like the classic example of .Fail/.Succeed. For instance:

```
enum Result {
    .Fail(String)     // Error message.
    .Succeed(MyType)  // Something to work with.
}

guard let x = couldFail() case .Succeed(let y) else { return x }
// Use y safely here.
```

Now, this can be done in a bulky way like so:

```
let x = couldFail()
let y:MyType
switch x {
case .Succeed(let dummy) { y = dummy }
case .Fail: return x
}
```

I have fiddled around with various ways of pattern-matching with case statements outside of a switch, but to no avail. Could use exceptions but surely one of the intents of enum associated values is to enable something like this. Perhaps a custom operator? Maybe some SmartPerson™ has a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? `guard/case` with pattern matching:

```
let x = couldFail()
guard case let .Succeed(y) = x else { return x }
// y can safely be used here ...
```

If `x` is needed in the else-body then you have to assign it to
a variable first. Otherwise a one-liner would do:

```
guard case let .Succeed(y) = couldFail() else { return }
// y can safely be used here ...
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to cram your two statements into one. But that may be the best we can do. Still, it is a vast improvement over the bulky way.

Comment: @AndrewDuncan: A variable which is declared in the guard condition is not usable in the body, so that's the best I could find.